# Sync custom product price by product category on cart items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, price

i have to arrange product price based on category . So every product in category A have price 5 , 
and in  category B product price is 10 and in  category c product price is 15 .

After this arrangement , when product is adding to cart , then i have to multiply product price by our margin .  Currently our margin is 2.5.

So we write following codes in `fucntions.php`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'product_price_new', 10, 2);
 function product_price_new($price, $product) {
     if(!is_cart()){
     if(has_term( 'accessories', 'product_cat' ,$product->id)){  $price=5; }
     if(has_term( 'hoodies', 'product_cat' ,$product->id)){ $price=10; }
     if(has_term( 'tshirts', 'product_cat' ,$product->id)){ $price=15;}

     }
     return $price;
 }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'margin_price', 30, 3 );
function margin_price( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $the_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    $product = wc_get_product( $the_id );
    $product_price = (float) $product->get_price(); 
    $cart_item_data['calculated-price'] = $product_price*2.5;
    return $cart_item_data;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_caculted', 20, 1 );
function add_caculted( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! empty( $cart_item['calculated-price'] ) ){
            // Set the calculated item price (if there is one)
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['calculated-price'] );

        }
    }
}
```

Please see what happen .

For example if we are trying to add product in category hoodies , so price will be , 10 *2.5=25

> (1) in cart page product pric is showing 25 , and this is correct .
>   [mywebsite.com/cart]
>
> (2) In checkout page product price is showing 10, so the total is
>   coming as 10 .   This is wrong it should be 25 .
>
> (3) In the minicart that showing near the menu , it showing 1*10 and subtotal is 10 , but it NEED to show 1 *25 and subtotal = 25

[image]

Please help to solve this issue . What i missed ?

i tried all this code in default woocommerce storfront theme . https://woocommerce.com/storefront/

Comment: What are your products types in your shop… are they only simple or also variable with variations?

Comment: only simple products

Comment: How are set your tax in your settings options for: 1) 
Prices entered with tax…  2) Display prices in the shop… 3) Display prices during cart and checkout

Comment: hii, there is no tax option . I just insatlled a wordpress and after that i installed storefront theme , So there is no other plugins also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for **simple products**, you can try the following instead:

```
// Utility function
function get_special_product_category_prices( $price, $product_id ) {
    // HERE your prices by product category
    $prices_by_cat = array( 5 => 'accessories', 10 => 'hoodies', 15 => 't-shirts' );
    foreach( $prices_by_cat as $key_price => $term ){
        if( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            return $key_price;
    }
    return $price;
}

// Alter product displayed prices (for simple products only)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'alter_displayed_price_html', 20, 2 );
function alter_displayed_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        $raw_price = get_special_product_category_prices( $product->get_price(), $product->get_id() );

        if( $raw_price > 0 )
            $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $raw_price ) ) );
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_calculated_margin_price', 30, 3 );
function add_calculated_margin_price( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $the_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    $product = wc_get_product( $the_id );

    $product_price = (float) get_special_product_category_prices( $product->get_price(), $product_id );

    $cart_item_data['calculated-price'] = $product_price * 2.5;
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_caculated_price', 20, 1 );
function set_caculated_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! empty( $cart_item['calculated-price'] ) ){
            // Set the calculated item price (if there is one)
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['calculated-price'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). It should work.

Comment: when i try this code add to cart button disappeared .

Comment: may be you are setting price for each product in backend product page . I din't add any price in backend product page.

Comment: But really thank you friend . I will check this code and chek the possibility . But the mincart is always making problem .

Comment: actually i try tyour code and i understand that i have to setup the price manually in baceknd so i did this and test the code again . So it is working . But still there is probel in mincart . When adding product this mincart showing product orginal price without multiply by 2.5 . But if we go to cart page and update the product quantity then after refresh the mincart is showing new price ,that i wanted  . So the problem is coming in mincart

Comment: @abilasher I have the same thing in cart and in minicart… **You can't ask questions on NOT normal woocommerce installation without telling it in your question** about the specific settings of your installation. Because you loose time, we (answerers) loose time and that questions/answers are not useful for the community

Comment: sorry friend .. But all your answers are very helpful to me every time